# Masonry layout is loading with height 0px

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

I'm trying to load images into a simple masonry.js layout, with images loaded first, and it looks like masonry is applying height: 0px to both the grid and grid items. Any idea why this is happening? Here is the js I am using, and a codepen.

http://codepen.io/kathryncrawford/pen/WwGVNa

JS

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var $container = $('.js-grid').imagesLoaded( function() { 

console.log("images are loaded");
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.js-masonry',
        columnWidth: 100
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your CodePen just says "loading......." for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That's weird...try this link? http://codepen.io/kathryncrawford/full/WwGVNa/

Comment: You won't "see" anything technically. But it shouldn't say loading either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the HTML in the [Masonry docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html), you notice that img's are always wrapped inside a div. Just surround your img's with divs.

```
<div class="js-grid">
    <div class="js-masonry">
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/600" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="js-masonry">
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/200" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="js-masonry">
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/200" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="js-masonry">
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="js-masonry">
        <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

See [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZdqrJ).